# Bixby: Want to use capsule-categories for category events

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am using capsule-categories for category events

```
capsule {
    capsule-categories {
        category (Events)
    }
}
```

We are using the latest version of Bixby(7.8.1-r19x.13460).

All the libraries are updated as per the document.

But using Events as a category is throwing error as "Events" is not a valid category[deprecation 6731].

Here is the Bixby documentation Url which I am using: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/categories.Events.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. We are looking into this and will post an update here: https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved. You should be able to use the `Events` category without any issues.

Comment: Yes... Thank you so much.